# Displaying Foreign language results in "?" in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, text, encoding

I am writing an application that displays Navajo text and currently it is working using the "Navajo Verdana" font. The only problem is that the glottal stop is being displayed as "?". The text is being displayed in a regular textblock.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                       Visibility="{Binding IsText, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter} }"
                       Foreground="{Binding Tag.ScreenSettings.ForegroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                       FontSize="22" 
                       FontFamily="{Binding Tag.ScreenSettings.CurrentFontFamily, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                       TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
```

I realize that this is usually an encoding issue and I have been trying different encodings to see if it changes anything. I've used UTF8, ISO-8859-1, and windows-1252. No matter what encoding I use it still displays the same. The file displays fine in MS Word using the same font so I know that the file is correct.

Here is the code that loads the file:

```
public static Song LoadSong(string key)
    {
        var stream = File.OpenRead(key);
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var wholeSong = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var song = new Song(wholeSong, key);

        sr.Close();

        return song;
    }
```

Here is the code that converts the encoding:

```
public string ChangeEncoding(string text)
    {
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        Encoding ascii = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] asciiBytes = ascii.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(ascii, iso, asciiBytes);
        string msg = iso.GetString(utf8Bytes);
        return msg;
    }
```

I cant figure out what is going on as all of the other parts of the font are working. Anybody have any ideas I can try?

Comment: Looks like you load the file wrong into the TextBox. (At first I thought you copied and pasted the text but then this ***The file displays*** made me think another way). So please post the code loading file into your textbox.

Comment: Sorry I miss typed. It should be textblock. To load the text into the textblock I am using a databing. Ill post the code.

Comment: so the `Text` in your ViewModel should be wrong. How is it loaded?

Comment: I added the loading and converting code. See edits. Ignore the variable names in the encoding editing code. I didnt bother switching the names as I tried different encodings.

Comment: Are you sure the file is just a plain text file? Also what exactly the `Text` is assigned to?

Comment: Since when is Navajo 1252.  Did you try full unicode.

Comment: It is not possible to consistently recover the correct text after it was mangled by StreamReader.  You **must** pass the correct Encoding to its constructor.  If you have no idea what it might be then Encoding.Default is normally the next best guess.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! You were correct. I passed Encoding.Default into the constructor of StreamReader and it worked. Post your comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Meh, you tried the next random thing you could do and it worked.  Congratulations, it doesn't make a good answer however.  Nor a guarantee it will work on the next file.  I'm a bit curious about "Navajo" though...